# How to print results of several of if-statements, like (5, 7, 3, ...), in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, nltk

So I'm working with some documents in which I count certain words, see what share they take up of their respective document, and see how these shares compare between different documents.

Here's the pseudo-code of what I'm doing:

```
if(share doc 1 < share doc 2): (share doc 1 / share doc 2)

else: (share doc 2 / share doc 1)
```

The result is printed as 0.7821... , or something like that.

Now, as an example, when I put in:

```
5+7, 8*3
```

The results print to (12, 24)

Is there a way of doing this with my if-else statements too? Something in the manner of:

```
[if(share doc 1 < share doc 2): (share doc 1 / share doc 2)

else: (share doc 2 / share doc 1)], 

[if(share doc 3 < share doc 4): (share doc 3 / share doc 4)

else: (share doc 3 / share doc 4)], ...
```

Print: (0.7823, 0.5682, ...)

I've tried putting in parenthesis in different places, but only get the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and it points to the 'if' at the beginning.

If you need more detail, let me know. Thank you!

Edit: To clarify, I have around 88 documents to do this with, a process which is extremely repetitive/time-consuming to do with each document-pair one at a time. What I want is for me to paste all the code, I'd otherwise copy-paste over and over, put in the parenthesis (or whatever it turns out to be) and just print a list of all results.

Edit 2: I got it working, but the user who posted the answer deleted their post. He recommended I'd change the syntax, it looked something like this:

```
(share doc 1 / share doc 2) if (share doc 1 < share doc 2) else (share doc 2 / share doc 1)
```

It worked wonders! I'll however mark the only other answer I got as the solution, even though it was not the method I used, so that this post is resolved.

Comment: Append the different results to a list and then print the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(share_doc_1 < share_doc_2): 
    x = (share_doc_1 / share_doc_2)
else: 
    x = (share_doc_2 / share_doc_1) 

if(share_doc_3 < share_doc_4): 
    y = (share_doc_3 / share_doc_4)

else: 
    y = (share_doc_3 / share_doc_4)

print (x,y)
```